# How would I concatenate this variable?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert text data into my sqlite database. I want to use a variable to store the text that I want stored in my database. I apologize if I haven't provided enough information. I'm unaware if more information is required to solve this problem or not. Here's what I have so far:

```
var MYVAR = 'The text';
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test_table (data1) VALUES (?)', [MYVAR]);
```

This produces an "undefined" for me when I query my database doing this

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test_table (data1) VALUES (?)', ['Text here']);
```

When querying the database, I alert the results and the "Text here" string is shown, so it is properly stored.

Comment: Did you have a question? I mean, you've got code there. Does it do what you want? If not, what does it do instead?

Comment: You need to at least tell people what sql library you're using. Ofcourse what you provided is not enough information. How do you expect people to help you? Read your mind?

Comment: @Strelok, No. I thought possibly, the syntax needed to concatenate properly could be given without needing that additional information.

Comment: @codebmanj Why do you think you need to concatenate anything?

Comment: @melpomene because I get undefined returned when using the variable.

Comment: @codebmanj Undefined returned from what?

Comment: @melpomene When I query the database for the results, I get undefined but if I use a string instead of a variable, the string is stored. I know because I alert the results.

Comment: @codebmanj http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Declare the $MYVAR variable inside the VALUES() and wrap it in double quotes.

```
$MYVAR = 'The text';
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test_table (data1) VALUES ("$MYVAR")");
```

Comment: @melpomone what language are you using?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: @melpomone  you must have an error within function... post your code so we know what tx and executeSql is, did you write this or is it part of some framework?

Comment: I literally copy/pasted your two lines into the browser console. `tx` is undefined, but that doesn't matter because the code never runs because it's a *expletive* syntax error.

Comment: @melpomene I'm using PHP are using JS? if so you really should be declaring queries on the client-side where your allowing people to map your database...

Comment: Why are you using PHP when the code in the question starts with `var MYVAR` and it's tagged "javascript"?

Comment: @melpomene assuming your using PHP not JS from what I mentioned above... if your getting - "tx is undefined"... then you have a problem when that object.function post the code and I'll take a look. If we are using JS here then like I said I'd advise against it but If you still want to use it i'll edit it out.

Comment: I just tried your (new) code in PHP. It said `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$MYVAR' (T_VARIABLE)` - still a syntax error. (Also, I'm not getting "tx is undefined" - are you just making stuff up?)

Comment: @melpomene I assumed that like I mentioned above it be very stupid to declare your database queries client-side "var" is a keyword in PHP as well although deprecated it still works just fine... now that I know you using JS... are you still going to use it? if so post your code so I can take a look at your broken "tx" - object and or "executeSql" -method

Comment: Quoting myself: "I literally copy/pasted your two lines". **There is no code for me to post**. I'm only running what you wrote.

Comment: @melpomene forget the tx error my PHP code obviously won't work in JS... You must have an error within your object.method (tx.executeSql) somewhere between creating an asynchronous request, transcoding that string (query) properly, and connecting to the database. Can you list your code?

Comment: @melpomene where did you get this (tx)-object and (executeSql)-method then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84964/discussion-between-jordan-davis-and-melpomene).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry again for not providing as much information as you may have needed to help me. I was unaware that more information was needed for this particular scenario. I figured out how to do it properly.

```
 var MYVAR = 'The text';
 tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test_table (data1) VALUES (?), ('" + MYVAR + "')");
```